# Display featured posts first, then display all others within a specific category in WordPress

Tags: php, categories, filters, query

I want to display featured posts first, then all other posts not marked as featured on a category archive page. I am using a plugin that has functionality to mark posts as featured. I have figured out how to pull in those posts, but I'm unsure how to *also* include posts not marked as featured.

I tried creating two separate queries and then merging them together, but it's not putting the featured posts at the top. It also has to work for pagination and only show the featured posts on the first page, not the second, third, etc.

```
function get_cat_posts( $query ) {
  if ( $query->is_category() ) {
    $current_category = get_queried_object_id();
    $category_slug = get_term_by( 'id', $current_category, 'category' )->slug;
    $featured = get_option('featured_' . $category_slug );

    $featured_query = array(
      'post__in' => $featured
    );
    $featured_query = new WP_Query($featured_query);
    
    $regular_query = get_posts(array(
      'post__not_in' => $featured
    ));
    $regular_query = new WP_Query($regular_query);
    
    $query->posts = array_merge($featured_query->posts, $regular_query->posts);
  }
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'get_cat_posts' );
```

Comment: can you rephrase your question/title using different words? What do you mean by display featured images first? The code block your shared has nothing to do with featured images

Comment: @TomJNowell I just updated my post to include additional info on the featured part.

Comment: ah I thought you might have meant posts that have featured images, but without knowing anything about this plugin it's not something that can be answered in a generic way. You might need to ask this in the community for that plugin or their support routes as 3rd party plugin support is offtopic here

Comment: @TomJNowell, Unfortunately, it's just a small plugin that I created. I've updated my post to include an example I tried having two separate queries, and then merging them, but didn't have any luck.

Comment: if it's a plugin you've written yourself then that's ok, but you'll need to share details of what makes a post a featured post, and how the plugin identifies them from non-featured posts

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm using `get_option` to select posts featured within a specific category. I've updated my code above.